# How to pass rustflags to artifact dependency binary?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to find a way to pass rustflags to artifact dependency bin.

Below is the story.

I write my toy OS currently, and using artifact dependency because this is suggested at rust-osdev/bootloader repositiory(descriptions are Booting section of this [README](https://github.com/rust-osdev/bootloader/blob/main/README.md)) and I thought this is a useful way. However, I find that this way seems not to pass rustflags I attached in `.cargo/config.toml` in my kernel workspace like below.

```
[build]
target = "x86_64-unknown-none"
rustflags = ["-C", "relocation-model=static", "-C", "link-arg=-no-pie"]

[unstable]
build-std = ["core", "compiler_builtins"]
build-std-features = ["compiler-builtins-mem"]
```

In above config, I expect that kernel elf type is `EXEC`, but actually, that type is `DYN`, i.e. I got PIE Elf file even though I write static and no pie flags.

I tried some patterns like below.

1. run `cargo build` directly in kernel workspace directory
2. set invalid rustflags like `link-args=hoge` and run `cargo build` in root project directory

As a result

1. non pie elf (Elf type is `EXEC`) is created with no errors.
2. **no errors appeared** while compile even if I run `cargo clean` before build.

That's why, I suspect the rustflags I wrote in `.cargo/config.toml` does not work when its workspace is treated as binary artifact dependency.

Reproduction code is [here](https://github.com/Soya-Onishi/rustflags-not-passed).

If there is a way to pass rustflags, please teach me.

Comment: Can you try setting the rust flags in the `build.rs` script instead of `.cargo/config.toml`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#rustc-flags

Comment: Thanks for your reply! You mean add build.rs into kernel workspace directory? I added build.rs with `println!("cargo:rustc-flags=-C relocation-model=static -C link-arg=-no-pie` in my kernel workspace. However, unfortunately, I got an error that says `-L` or `-l`  are only acceptable flags.

Comment: I think you need `cargo:rustc-cdylib-link-arg=-no-pie` for that one. I'm not sure about `relocation-model=static`. You might also want to try https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/unstable.html#profile-rustflags-option

Comment: `cargo:rust-link-arg=-no-pie` is what I need! Thanks for your advice! Although there is still wonder why rustflags in `<kernel workspace>/.cargo/config.toml` is ignored, I close this question once. If needed, above question will be post at another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Add your `build.rs` in workspace, `<project root path>/<kernel workspace name>/build.rs` in my case, and put script like below in it.

```
fn main() {
  println!("cargo:rust-link-arg=-no-pie");
}
```